# Preserving (or restoring) whitespace in TextContent

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Using AngleSharp to process some HTML and extract the text content of an element for later mining, I've run into a problem with the way AngleSharp strips out the HTML tags. For example, I have a piece of HTML something like this (minus the newlines and tabs):

```
<div id="someID">
    blah, blah, blah, blah
    blah, blah, 
    <ul>
        <li><i>action.</i></li>
        <li><i>Typical, blah, blah, blah</li>
    </ul>
    blah, blah, blah
</div>
```

The problem here, is when I get the `TextContent`:

```
var content = someDiv.TextContext;
```

It'll come out like this:

```
"...blah, blah, action.Typical blah, blah..."
```

The words `action` and `Typical` have been smashed together without any whitespace (because the only thing between them are html tags). This is tripping up my efforts to then tokenize the text content because `action.Typical` is seen as a single word instead of two words.

I could, of course, just run a search and replace (probably using a regex), something like `(\S)\.(\S)` and replace it with `$1. $2` but then that would take something like `www.somecompany.com` and split it up into `www`, `somecompany` and `com` and I *might* want to preserve that (or failing that `www` and `com` aren't likely to be very useful anyway by themselves). I could exclude words with more than one dot, but a web address might appear as `somecompany.com` (without the `www`) or you might encounter an email address like `somebody@somecompany.com`.

Is there a robust way around this? To preserve at least one space after the tags have been stripped out?

Comment: Is that really the HTML you are parsing (literally)? Because if it would be, then AngleSharp would certainly have spaces (in fact a new line and some space characters) between "action." and "typical".

Comment: @FlorianRappl: Actually no, I formatted it for clarity, but in truth it's a single line without line breaks or tabs. I guess that part is a bit confusing. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Yep, I guessed so. As I said: Otherwise, you would see the text of the text nodes in between. I'll provide another way / answer, which may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like the best way to fix this is to recurse down the `ChildNodes` (not `Children` which misses text nodes) of the root element and then join them altogether again. So, given:

```
var rootElem = myDoc.GetElementById("someId");
```

I can create a function like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> ExtractChildNodes(INode node)
{
    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (var c in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (var r in ExtractChildNodes(c))
            {
                yield return r;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield return node.TextContent;
    }
}
```

That will test if a node has child nodes and if it does drill-down to the lowest leaf node and return the text from there. I can then do this:

```
var textContentWithSpacesBetweenNodes = string.Join(" ", ExtractChildNodes(rootElem));
```

And that *should* give me:

```
"...blah, blah, action. Typical blah, blah..."
```

With the space between `action` and `Typical`.

This seems to cope with not just situations like `<p>some.</p><p>words</p>` but also self-closing tags like `some</br>words` or even `some<br>words` which would be a massive pain to deal with using a regex or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe works, except for some of the scenarios that you already encountered (e.g., self-closing tags). Therefore, I propose the following:

- text nodes will be taken literally
- elements iterate over their child nodes, w.r.t.

  - if two adjacent elements yield content, a space is inserted
  - if there are no child nodes look if the element is special (such as br) and place some representative string (e.g., newline)
  - otherwise, e.g., if a text node is adjacent to an element, no text is inserted

So overall the following implementation should do the job:

```
String Stringify(INode node)
{
    switch (node.NodeType)
    {
        case NodeType.Text:
            return node.TextContent;

        case NodeType.Element:
            if (node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                var isElement = false;

                foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    var isPreviousElement = isElement;
                    var content = Stringify(child);
                    isElement = child.NodeType == NodeType.Element;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(content) && isElement && isPreviousElement)
                    {
                        sb.Append(' ');
                    }

                    sb.Append(content);
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }

            switch (node.NodeName.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "br": return "\n";
            }

            goto default;

        default:
            return String.Empty;

    }
}
```

The advantage of such an implementation is that you can really adjust it to your needs. As an example, for tags such as `br` you can easily output spaces instead of newlines.